# try: except: pass but in Go? (make Go not crash when there is a network issue ?)

Tags: go

I am having issues when sometimes I try to scrape a page (a couple of RSS;s and image sites) but some times there is a connection error

How can you handle a Go error without having to deal/handle without Go crashing itself?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Manager struct {
    threadCount                     int
}
var (
    message                 = map[string]interface{}{}
    messageMutex            = sync.RWMutex{}
)

func startGo(bManager Manager) {
    for{
        messageMutex.RLock()
        fmt.Println("hey")
        ScrapeImages()
        messageMutex.RUnlock()
    }
}    

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    
    stall := make(chan struct{})
    bManager := Manager{
        threadCount:     5,
    }

    for i := 0; i < bManager.threadCount; i++ {
        go startGo(bManager)
    }
    <-stall
}
```

Comment: So, you don't want to be checking errs, correct?

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducible sample: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example -- your code doesn't show `ScrapImages`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question displays lack of the very basic Go foundations. Please start [here](https://golang.org/doc/); in particular, start with [The Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Go encourages programmers to handle errors instead of ignoring them. See this post for details: https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

That said, Go also doesn't tend to "crash when there's a network issue". The `net/http` functions will return errors when issues occur, and you can handle these errors as needed in your program. E.g. in your case `ScrapeImages` would likely return an `error`.

If you have code that `panics`s, you can use `recover` to catch the panic and react in some way. In a very approximate way this is akin to Python's `except: pass`, as you mention. For example, the `net/http` HTTP server recovers from panics in handlers by logging out an error and continuing serving other requests. Thus a panic in handling one request won't crash the whole server.